# Fragment not attached to Activity when back pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have an implementation of fragment as explained [here](https://github.com/AmirHadifar/Flashcard/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/hadifar/dope/ui/fragment/BaseFragment.java). I have expanded the BaseFragment class to handle navigation icon onClickListener. The code for that looks like this,

```
private void onBackButtonPressed(int tag)
    {
        switch (tag)
        {
            case Global.DISPLAY_STORE:
            {
                setTitle("Loyalty Cards",Color.BLACK);
                setToolBar(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), Global.ADD_CARD,R.drawable.add_round_btn);
                break;

            }
            case Global.ADD_CARD:
            {
                setTitle("Wallet", Color.WHITE);
                setToolBar(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), Global.DISPLAY_STORE,R.drawable.icon_shopping);
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                break;
            }
            case Global.CARD_DETAILS:
            {
                setTitle("Loyalty Cards",Color.BLACK);
                setToolBar(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), Global.ADD_CARD,R.drawable.add_round_btn);
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

I am using this block of code to change the ToolBar icons and colors when back button is pressed.This code resides in BaseFragment.

Here is how I implement the code to handle back press,

I have my fragment extending the BaseFragment

```
public class CardDetailsFragment extends BaseFragment
```

Now inside the BaseFragment onCreate I have this code,

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        ImageButton righBarButton = (ImageButton) mainActivity.getToolbar().findViewById(R.id.btn_ToolBarRightBtn);
        righBarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRighBarButtonClicked(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()));
            }
        });

        mainActivity.getToolbar().setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackButtonPressed(BACK_BUTTON_TAG);
            }
        });

        getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);

        shouldDisplayHomeUp();
    }
```

By this every fragments back button press and the right bar button item click in toolbar are handled.

Consider the scenario I have three fragments A , B and C.

From Fragment A I open Fragment B and Then Fragment C. Now From fragment C I click the back button to reach fragment B. The back button event is handled by above code and it works fine.

Now from Fragment B, I click the back button to reach Fragment A. But when I click back button I am getting exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment CardDetailsFragment{d8b35b5} not attached to Activity
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:636)
```

> here the CardDetailsFragment is the FragmentC, but I am clicking the
>   back button from Fragment B

Comment: How is the fragment getting the event to call `onBackButtonPressed()`?

Comment: I have updated the pst

Comment: Try to store instance of fragment in Back stack  and load it on back press

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time the user presses the back button, Fragment C is no longer necessary and thus it is detached from the activity.  The problem lies in the fact that even though Fragment C is detached, it is still registered as a listener for back stack change events.

The second time the user presses the back button, your `onBackStackPressed()` method is called in Fragment C.  When `getResources()` is executed, there is no activity attachment so `getResources()` fails.

Something like this in your fragment should fix it:

```
     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
         getFragmentManager().removeOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
         super.onDestroy();
     }
```